# Accessing Has Many Through

Tags: cakephp

Hi I'm a Rails programmer on my first foray in to CakePHP but seem to have hit a bit of a wall:

I have the following relationships:

```
BookStore has_many Books
Book belongs_to BookStore
Book has_and_belongs_to_many Authors
Author has_and_belongs_to_many Books
```

If I have a BookStore instance how can I get at the list of Authors for that BookStore so I can iterate over it in my view?

Many thanks in advance,
Ash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you have the relationships set up correctly in the models, CakePHP will do most of the work for you. A good guide on doing this can be found at http://book.cakephp.org/view/1000/Models.

```
$authors = $this->Author->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Bookstore.id' => $id,
    ),
));

$this->set('authors', $authors);
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I'd forgotten I'd posted on here! I'd managed to solve it in the meantime in the same way you suggested - only thing I needed was to add a group on Author.id to remove some duplicates in the results.